# Query Datetime Declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble with a `Datetime` column in a table while adding declaration on a stored procedure.

I want to set `@EventTime` as a day of the week without modifying the column..

More like a catch.

For example:

```
declare @EventTime datetime

set @EventTime = (select EventTime 
                  from _LogClients 
                  where ClientID = @ClientID)

if (@EventTime like '%2-2%) -- As a day of a week not as a numerical date.
```

- - Datetime preview:2019-01-22 17:47:00

Any help regarding that matter?
Note:
The EventTime is used on a Stored Procedure which runs on a certain event that occur.. However, the database is a Game one, so the logger is based on the server files, I need to know if I'm able to make the EventTime declaration able to read the datetime from the column as weekday in order to execute a certain query for that day (Not SQL Agent based though.. that's a different story).

Comment: What does it mean to set a parameter as "day of the week"?  Sample data and desired results would definitely help as would a database tag.

Comment: the weekday function? the `datepart(w, @EventTime)`?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @dlatikay
So, let me make myself clear.. The EventTime is used on a Stored Procedure which runs on a certain event that occur.. However, the database is a Game one, 
so the logger is based on the server files, I need to know if I'm able to make the EventTime declaration able to read the datetime from the column as weekday in order to execute a certain query for that day (Not SQL Agent based though.. that's a different story).

Comment: @samkart it's game database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The EventTime is used on a Stored Procedure which runs on a certain event that occur.. However, the database is a Game one, so the logger is based on the server files, I need to know if I'm able to make the EventTime declaration able to read the datetime from the column as weekday in order to execute a certain query for that day (Not SQL Agent based though.. that's a different story).

Comment: Please try to include the relevant information in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question if you are trying to get the numerical representation of the actual day of the week (like Sunday would be "1", Monday as "2", etc.. ) or if you just need the day of the week as a word from a date.

Here is your code modified to use the word for the day of the week (please note you could have used the DateName within the select statement but then you'd need to change the type of @EventTime to a nVarchar() or nchar) :

```
declare @EventTime datetime

set @EventTime = (select EventTime 
              from _LogClients 
              where ClientID = @ClientID)

if (DATENAME(dw,@EventTime) like '%Tuesday%)
```

If you wanted the numerical equivalent use:

```
if (DATEPART(dw,@EventTime) = '1' -- Testing for Sunday day name
```

Comment: I'll try both of them!

Comment: OK, I tried both of them didn't work out. The datetime is 2019-01-22 17:47:00.. Seems like the stored procedure won't select it as weekday..